# use outlook instead of gmail to send mails vb.net 2010

Tags: email, vb.net-2010

I have a class to send emails with multiple attachments, it uses gmail, but how can I use Outlook to send emails?

```
   Imports System.Net.Mail
    Imports System.Net.Mime


    Public Sub SendThis(ByVal SubjectText As String, _
                             ByVal BodyText As String, _
                             ByVal FromAddress As String, _
                             ByVal ToAddress As String, _
                             Optional ByVal FileName As Collection = Nothing _
                             )
            Try
                Dim email As New Net.Mail.MailMessage(FromAddress, ToAddress)
                email.Subject = SubjectText
                email.Body = BodyText
                If Not FileName Is Nothing Then
                    For Each Name As String In FileName
                        Dim attach As New Net.Mail.Attachment(Name) 'Includes Path
                        email.Attachments.Add(attach)
                    Next
                    For Each At As Attachment In email.Attachments
                        At.TransferEncoding() = Net.Mime.TransferEncoding.Base64
                    Next
                End If
                Dim TheSmtp As New SmtpClient(YourSmtpServerName, 587)
                TheSmtp.Credentials = New Net.NetworkCredential("abc@gmail.com","MYPASS")
                TheSmtp.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network
                TheSmtp.Send(email)
                email.Attachments.Clear()
                TheSmtp = Nothing
                email = Nothing    
            Catch ex As Exception
                MessageBox.Show("Error: " & ex.Message, "HFB", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)
            End Try
        End Sub
```

I call the function like:

```
      Private Sub BtnSend_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles BtnSend.Click
            Dim BodyText As String
            Dim SubjectText As String
            Dim FromAddress As String
            Dim ToAddress As String
            Dim Filename As New Collection
            If Me.LstBxAttach.Items.Count > 0 Then
                For Each TheItem As String In LstBxAttach.Items
                    Filename.Add(TheItem)
                Next
            End If
            SubjectText = Me.TbSubject.Text
            BodyText = Me.TbBody.Text
            SendThis(SubjectText, _
                          BodyText, _
                          "from@example.com", _
                          "to@example.com", _
                          Filename _
                          )
            SubjectText = ""
            BodyText = ""
            FromAddress = ""
            ToAddress = ""
            MessageBox.Show("Sent!", "HFB", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
        End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [Outlook object model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms268893.aspx). The [Application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.application.aspx) object lets you connect to Outlook; to send an e-mail, you will want to create a [MailItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.mailitem.aspx) object, populate the relevant properties, and call its [Send](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/microsoft.office.interop.outlook._mailitem.send.aspx) method.